# Mac Os El Capitan is sharing the content of one mac to another

Tags: macos, mac, osx-el-capitan

I have 2 macminis in the same network. Yesterday, I updated both of them, and now if I open safari and type google.com, facebook.com, etc. An icon appear in the dock of the other mac suggesting me to open safari with the same web. The same happens with mail, and another apps from apple.

How I can disable this behavior?

Comment: Is your user account linked with your iCloud account? If so, make sure to check system preferences and disable the 'handoff' setting with it. I remember seeing an option for it somewhere in there. Sorry if I cannot be more helpful.

Comment: Thank yoou, it seems to be the handoff option in General Settings.

Comment: That's it! I remember it was something like that.